# Knex - How to create table (and change schema) without using migrations

Tags: knex.js

i'm trying to create tables / columns with knex... but without using migrations. but this code...

```
var miDb =require('knex')({client: 'pg', connection: myConexStr});
miDb.schema.createTable('xample', function(table) {
    table.increments();
    table.string('nombre');
});
```

Only runs as expected when it's executed within a "migration"

When it's executed somewhere else (i.e. during app boot) it doesn't create the table...

The `table.increments()` line is never reached.

Seems that "schema methods" only works at migrations.

Or maybe i forgot something to do...

TIA

Answer (score 0):

As brian_miller says me at IRC, i'd better catch the promise to see if there is an error.
No error occurs, but when i call .then/.catch from the promise the code run as expected.

i.e. that works:

```
var miDb =require('knex')({client: 'pg', connection: myConexStr});
miDb.schema.createTable('xample', function(table) {
    table.increments();
    table.string('nombre');
})
.then(function(obj) {console.log(obj)})
.catch(function(err) {console.log(err)});
```

And the table was created.